# QGIS attributes pop-up window is empty

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

I have a problem with QGIS (2.2 and 2.4). Sometimes, when I'm going to insert some new features on a layer, the pop-up window that appears at the end is empty (all gray, no attributes are displayed). So I must open the table and insert the new values. It happens even if I use layers from postgis or shape files.
Its not a problem of the layer because the same layer used in another machine does not have this problem.
Someone have the same problem? Could it be a problem linked to some plugin?

EDIT:
Ok now I can replicate the error. If I load a shape file with no style I don't have any problem. If I apply a style (from qml or from database postgres) it happens. Tested on the pc, with a clean qgis 2.4 installation.

Can someone confirm to me the error?

Comment: Have you checked http://hub.qgis.org/ ? This problem can be already reported. If it is happening only sometimes, it can be hard to replicate it to find what is the real issue though.

Comment: After a fast research I didn't find this problem described on hub.qgis.org. Maybe I have to open a ticket...

Comment: You can try but I think as far as it is not happening (can't be replicated) with clean single install of QGIS 2.4 there is not much chance there will be done something with it.

Comment: I agree with @Miro... I am not able to duplicate the error on 3 separate systems running 2.2 and 2.4...

Comment: Ok thanks for help, I'll try to make a clean install of qgis. Sounds like the only solution.

Comment: Ok now I can replicate the error. If I load a shape file with no style I don't have any problem. If I apply a style (from qml or from database postgres) it happens. Tested on the pc, with a clean qgis 2.4 installation.

Can someone confirm to me the error?

Answer (score 1):

It does not seem like a plugin problem, because it works on other systems. Re-install QGIS and try. I have faced a similar issue in case two versions of QGIS are simultaneously installed.

Comment: I have three version of qgis on my pc and I don't have the problem on this machine.. (but I have it on another one with 2 versions of qgis installed). So I don't think that the problem is there.